# Ajax multiple ajax request from online file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function addIDS() {
  const imdbIDs = [];
  imdbIDs.push("id1");
  imdbIDs.push("id2");
  ...
  return imdbIDs ;
}

function getThemoviedbIDs(IDs) {
  let arr = [];
  let urls = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
    urls.push(`...${imdb_ids[i]}...`);
  }
  $.each(urls, (i, u) => {
    $(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: u,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          arr.push(data.tv_results[0].id);
        },
        statusCode: {
          404: function() {
            alert('Err');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
  return arr;
}

function getDetails(themoviedbID) {
  console.log(themoviedbID);
  console.log(`...${themoviedbID[0]}`);
}


const imdbIDs = addIDS();
console.log("IMDB IDs: ", imdbIDs);

const themoviedbIDs = getThemoviedbIDs(imdbIDs);
console.log("themoviedbIDs: ", themoviedbIDs);

const themoviedbIDs = getThemoviedbIDs(themoviedbIDs);
console.log("themoviedbIDs: ", themoviedbIDs);
```

I am using [themoviedb](https://www.themoviedb.org/) database.

`populate()` I add imdb IDs to the `imdbIDs` array, then I get themoviedb IDs by `getThemoviedbIDs()` function.

In the `getDetails()` function I would like to make ajax request just like in the `getThemoviedbIDs()` function, but unfortunatelly there is a problem in there. `console.log(themoviedbID)` output the appropriate array, but `console.log(...${themoviedbID[0]})` output `.../undefined...`

I can get enough information about the series if I am using themoviedb ID.

Comment: That's a super classic question. `getThemoviedbIDs` is asynchronous, but you are assigning it synchronously to a variable, and logging it immediately, so it's necessarily undefined. I have marked the question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call.

Comment: @JeremyThille maybe I do not understand it correctly. I put the function call between `(async () => {  .... })();` and put `await` before the function call like `const themoviedbIDs = await getThemoviedbIDs(imdbIDs)` but this is not working

Comment: Yeah but `$.each` is synchronous. By nature, asynchronous stuff can't work inside synchronous methods. My advice: dump jQuery, you really don't need `$.each` and `$.ajax`. Replace `$.each` with `for( ... )` and `$.ajax` with `await fetch(url)`. Also remove the `$(function() {` from your loop, it's got no business at all here (it means "when the document is ready").

Comment: https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/bGaGGvj?editors=1010